Building custom linux kernel using buildroot
I am trying to build a custom Linux kernel using Buildroot. I have to do it because I later want to use the generated kernel image and rootfs with the Jailhouse hypervisor. I am using the following kernel source downloaded from here
https://github.com/siemens/linux/tree/jailhouse-enabling/5.15-rt
I am using Buildroot to generate the kernel image and rootfs as I need a very small size kernel to be used with the hypervisor. I am doing the following steps when using Buildroot.
make menuconfig -> I use the menu to create a sample .config file. I adapt this minimal .config file to specify my kernel source location and the location of .config file using the kernel options in the menu. That part of the resulting .config file is shown below
> BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_TARBALL_LOCATION="file:///home/madox/Downloads/linux-jailhouse-enabling-5.15-rt.tar.gz"
> BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_VERSION="custom" BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_PATCH=""
> # BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_USE_DEFCONFIG is not set
> # BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_USE_ARCH_DEFAULT_CONFIG is not set BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_USE_CUSTOM_CONFIG=y
> BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_CONFIG_FILE="/home/madox/Downloads/linux-jailhouse-enabling-5.15-rt/.config" BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CONFIG_FRAGMENT_FILES="" 

However, I am getting the following errors when i use make after setting up the configurations.
>> linux custom Extracting
gzip -d -c /home/madox/Downloads/buildroot/dl/linux/linux-jailhouse-enabling-5.15-rt.tar.gz | tar --strip-components=1 -C /home/madox/Downloads/buildroot/output/build/linux-custom   -xf -
>>> linux custom Patching
for p in  ; do if test -d $p ; then PATH=/home/madox/Downloads/buildroot/output/host/bin:$PATH support/scripts/apply-patches.sh  /home/madox/Downloads/buildroot/output/build/linux-custom $p \*.patch || exit 1 ; else PATH=/home/madox/Downloads/buildroot/output/host/bin:$PATH support/scripts/apply-patches.sh  /home/madox/Downloads/buildroot/output/build/linux-custom `dirname $p` `basename $p` || exit 1; fi done
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'defconfig'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [linux/linux.mk:647: /home/madox/Downloads/buildroot/output/build/linux-custom/.stamp_dotconfig] Error 2

I would like to use a custom .config file to compile the kernel and that is the path I am specifying in BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_CONFIG_FILE. But it seems this is not the purpose of this field. Also, I am not using any patches as this kernel source already has everything I need but I am not able to disable the patch field (it is left empty).
Anyone can help me what I am doing wrong?
I just need a simple way to build my kernel using Buildroot using my .config file. or even if it is possible to build the kernel with some default configuration that generates a minimal size kernel it would also be fine.

"Anyone can help me what I am doing wrong?" - Start over with a make distclean. Find a Buildroot defconfig file (in the configs/ directory) that matches your target system (whatever that is), and issue a make XXX_defconfig. Then you can do a make menuconfig.

Thanks for the response, all I can see in configs/* are config files for different embedded boards. But I want to build the kernel for a normal x86_64 Linux PC. Any idea which config I can use?

How hard did you look? I see a pc_x86_64_bios_defconfig and pc_x86_64_efi_defconfig.

Do you have to BR options on a single line (as per last line in the excerpt)? Do you know the difference between dotconfig (.config) and defconfig? Do you think you need to supply the full path to the custom config file?

@sawdust Thanks for that, I can build the kernel using the defined config files as you pointed out but still when I try to use the same config file to build my custom kernel I am not able to do it and I am getting the same error. I just modify the custom kernel option in the buildroot by providing the path to my custom kernel.tar.bz file. I still can not comprehend what does BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_CONFIG_FILE=corresponds to, what should I set in this option when building a custom kernel using the source code.

Buildroot is a set of makefiles and scripts to build the Linux kernel and other software packages. Buildroot uses the same Kconfig system as the Linux kernel.
So you need to be cognizant of the top-layer of defconfig and .config files used by Buildroot itself and the lower-layers of defconfig and .config files used by the kernel and other packages (e.g. U-Boot and Busybox).

I am doing the following steps when using Buildroot.
make menuconfig

I use the menu to create a sample .config file. I adapt this minimal .config file >to specify my kernel source location and the location of .config file using the >kernel options in the menu.

The above shell command is for configuring Buildroot itself, i.e. the top layer. You can configure Buildroot to download a particular (mainline) Linux kernel version or use an alternate source tree or tarball.
But the resultant .config file is for the top-level Buildroot system.
You cannot use this .config file for the Linux kernel, i.e. as the value for BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_CONFIG_FILE (as you seem to do).

The steps to setup a custom Linux kernel configuration using Buildroot could be:

make distclean to start with a fresh Buildroot directory.

make XXX_defconfig to install a default Buildroot configuration.
Scan the configs/ subdirectory for an appropriate file for your target system.
For the x86_64 target, use either pc_x86_64_bios_defconfig or pc_x86_64_efi_defconfig.

make menuconfig to configure Buildroot.
Specify the location of your custom Linux kernel source.
Since pc_x86_64_XXX_defconfig already specifies a custom kernel defconfig (i.e. BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_CONFIG_FILE="board/pc/linux.config"), leave that alone.
Verify that the version number for kernel headers (under Toolchain) is not more recent than your custom kernel.

make linux-menuconfig to configure the Linux kernel.
This is the opportunity to specify "a very small size kernel" customized to your liking.
Beware that this step will require the toolchain and a few other host utilities to be available, so there could be significant compilation before the kernel menu is available.

make linux-update-config to save your (new) customized minimal-kernel configuration.
Note that this command will actually replace the previous (default) version in board/pc/linux.config.
Later, if necessary, you can make clean to start again with a fresh output/ subdirectory, but the kernel will be built with your most-recently updated/saved kernel configuration rather than the original default configuration.
See Buildroot - how to customise an existing kernel defconfig

make to build your custom kernel and packages for the root filesystem.

Test your new build on the target.
Repeat either steps #3 and/or #4 (+ #5) to tweak your Buildroot and/or kernel customizations. But beware of known issues regarding partial or incomplete rebuilds that may require a make clean.




I would like to use a custom .config file to compile the kernel and that is the path I am specifying in BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_CONFIG_FILE. But it seems this is not the purpose of this field.

No, that is the purpose of that configuration option (as its name asserts).
But is there a file at that path? Is there actually a /home/madox/Downloads/linux-jailhouse-enabling-5.15-rt/ subdirectory?
Such a file does not exist at that git repository, so what did you download?
FYI the "Error 2" in that message indicates "No such file or directory".

Also, I am not using any patches as this kernel source already has everything I need but I am not able to disable the patch field (it is left empty).

That message is simply to show script progress. There's no error to cause concern.


I can build the kernel using the defined config files as you pointed out but still when I try to use the same config file to build my custom kernel I am not able to do it and I am getting the same error. I just modify the custom kernel option in the buildroot by providing the path to my custom kernel.tar.bz file.

That does not make any sense. The Buildroot config should still have BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_CONFIG_FILE="board/pc/linux.config, which is not affected by specifying a custom kernel.
I have to assume you have omitted a salient detail to cause another "No such file or directory" error.
